# Bootstrap vuejs library - form datepicker

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap form datepicker from the bootstrap vuejs library. However, I am having a problem with the default date. I want the default value to be null if the user does not select any date since those two fields are not mandatory. However, when I click on the submit button, the datepicker value is automatically set to 1st January 1970 instead of null or an empty string.

```
data() {
    return {
        activeTo: "",
        activeFrom: ""
    }
},
methods: {
    Reset(){
        if (!this.form.activeFrom || !this.form.activeTo) {    
            this.form.activeFrom = null;
            this.form.activeTo = null;
        } else {
            this.form.activeFrom = new Date(this.form.activeFrom).toISOString();
            this.form.activeTo = new Date(this.form.activeTo).toISOString();
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: [value-as-date](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#v-model-return-value) prop seems to do just that

Comment: I've removed the C# tag because this doesn't seem related in any remote way to any C# code you may or may not have.

Comment: In the documentation, it has been mentioned that the `init-date` prop is served to address your issue. Please follow the link and let us know the result. If your problem persists, provide us with Vue and bootstrap-vue versions. Link: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#initial-open-calendar-date

Comment: None of these worked for me.